# Sitemap not being read correctly

Tags: xml, wordpress, search, sitemap

I'm having a drop in performance on a website and I'm wondering if it could have something to do with the sitemap not being read correctly. On my other sites when I click on the sitemap_index.xml in Google search console it shows the page map...etc. On this site it shows nothing. I can't figure out why this would be.

[image]

Comment: Did you open the sitemap url on the browser and check if it has the urls listed or not? I am guessing you're using RANKMATH SEO plugin so [here](https://rankmath.com/kb/sitemap-404-error/) are some problems and solutions listed by RankMath Team that you should check.

Comment: Yes I clicked on it and everything is listed there, but in GSC the pages and post maps aren't showing up. I'm using Yoast to generate the maps.